# PHP DateTime failing to convert Amazon shipping date

Tags: php

I've realised my DateTime function is not converting and returning false.

Example date/time as provided by Amazon. This is what I am trying to convert from:
`2020-07-28T23:00:00Z`

**Function which accepts the date as provided by Amazon and tries to convert it.**

```
protected function dateUtcToEuropeLondon($date)
{
    try {
        $dt = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
        $dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));

        return $dt;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Full function.**

```
// Detect if custom shipping date exists
$date = (isset($order_details->EarliestShipDate)) ? $order_details->EarliestShipDate : '';

// Set custom meta field so we can easily access it via WC_Order
if (!empty($date)) {
    $date = $this->dateUtcToEuropeLondon(strtotime($date));
    
    if ($date instanceof DateTime) {
        update_post_meta($order_id, '_wpl_shipping_date', $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'));
    }
}
```

For starters, I checked what value I got back from:
`$date = $this->dateUtcToEuropeLondon(strtotime('2020-07-28T23:00:00Z'));`
it was nothing: `''`.

Comment: _“it was nothing”_ - it was not an empty string, it was `false`. Which you returned in the catch block, apparently completely ignoring what the exception actually had to say.

Comment: You pass in a timestamp, not sure why, there is a DateTime->setTimestamp() method for that! Error was `DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (1595977200) at position 8 (0): Unexpected character` because the constructor expects a datetime string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to create a DateTime object using a UNIX timestamp (via strtotime) which is all numbers. What DateTime is expecting is the more 'human friendly' `d/m/y` style format - so you'll need to specify that what you're giving it is a 'unixtime' string, rather than a 'datetime' string -- subtle difference.

Try changing

```
$dt = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

to

```
$dt = new DateTime('@'.$date, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

Using an `@` at the start of the string will tell your `DateTime` object that you're sending in a unix timestamp. Once it's happy, it will then allow your function to determine the correct timezone from UTC to Europe/London (GMT/BST).